# object.method or method(object) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new at Ruby and currently learning blocks. As far as I see, there are two ways of calling a parameter to be used inside a block. The firs way is for example:

```
 def function (parameter)
      yield(x)
    end
```

so we can call the method by using

```
function{|x| print x}
```

My question is about defining a method by following the pattern `object.method`. For example

```
parameter.function{|x| #something }
```

How do you define the block to receive the `(1..100)` object just like, for example, the `each` method?:

```
(1..100).each{|x| print x}
```

Comment: You've got it backwards.  When you enter `3.something` in Ruby, `something` doesn't use `3`, but rather `3`'s class must have (or inherits) method `something`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function for the object. `(0..10)` is `Range`.

```
irb(main):002:0> (0..10).class
=> Range
```

```
class Range
  def function
    self.each {|i| yield i}
  end
end

(0..10).function {|i| print i}
#=> 012345678910
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is about defining a method by following the pattern `object.method`

If you write `obj.foo { ... }`, Ruby sends the *message* `foo` to `obj` (along with the block argument). It's up to `obj` to *respond* to it.

To make an object respond to a message, you usually define a *method* with the same name. Due to Ruby's [method lookup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup), there are several ways to do so:

#### Singleton class

You can define a method on the object itself via `def obj.foo`:

```
obj = (1..100)

def obj.foo
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
end

obj.foo { |x| puts x }
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

This method is exclusive to `obj`. Technically, it's defined in the object's *singleton class*.

#### Module (via extend)

It can also be defined in a [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Module.html):

```
module Foo
  def foo
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

obj = (1..100)
obj.extend(Foo)
obj.foo { ... }
```

By using [`extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html#extend-method) all methods from the module will be added to `obj`. (again via its singleton class)

#### Module (via include)

If you want to change *all instances* of a given class, you can [`include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Module.html#include-method) the module into their class:

```
Range.include(Foo)

(1..100).foo { ... }
```

#### Class

Last not least, you can (re-) open the class and add the method right there:

```
class Range
  def foo
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

(1..100).foo { ...}
```

You generally don't want to alter Ruby's core classes. But for your own classes, this is the usual and preferred way of defining instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have such method

```rb
def function(x)
  yield(x)
end
```

You can call it as

```
function("Hello") { |x| puts x } # will print "Hello"
```

But you can also call it with `self`:

```
self.function("Hello") { |x| puts x } # also will print "Hello"
```

Because actually in first example you call `function` for `main` object. You can check it:

```
self
# => main
```

So there is no difference in your examples. In Ruby you always apply the method to some object

If you need to define it, just define this method in some class

```
class MyClass
  def function(x)
    yield(x)
  end
end
```

And then call it

```
my_object = MyClass.new
my_object.function("Hello") { |x| puts x } # also will print "Hello"
```